# Delete from select

Tags: mysql, row, sql-delete

I'm trying to convert the following to a delete procedure but it doesn't seem to work.

```
SELECT i08.pe01 AS fld1,
i08.pe02 AS fld11,
i08.pe03 AS fld21,
i08.nr01 AS nr0
FROM i08
LEFT JOIN i00 ON i08.pe01=i00.pno
WHERE  (i00.p9901 ='17' &&
i08.pe01 not in (SELECT distinct        i01_KIN.p01 AS fld81 FROM i01_KIN))
```

I'm trying

```
DELETE FROM i08
USING i08, i00, i01_KIN
WHERE  (i00.p9901 ='17' &&
i08.pe01 not in (SELECT distinct     i01_KIN.p01 AS fld81 FROM i01_KIN))
```

But nothing.  Anyone who can help pls

Comment: does anything output if you change distinct to top 1

Comment: 'LEFT JOIN'ing a table and then using it an equality comparison in the WHERE clause effectively makes it an 'INNER JOIN'. Are you sure you meant to do this?

Comment: It makes no difference on the resultset between 'inner' or 'left' join. As for using top instead of distinct the results are the same

Comment: Btw when I try my delete statement the server get into an endless loop.

Comment: Does it matter if I change the order of the paremeteres? Ie.                                                                                WHERE  (i08.pe01 not in (SELECT distinct                                                                                                              i01_KIN.p01 AS fld81 FROM i01_KIN)) && i00.p9901 ='17'?

Answer (score 2):

if i'm not mistaken you shouldn't be using && but rather AND for MySQL

```
DELETE FROM i08
USING i08, i00, i01_KIN
WHERE  
(    i00.p9901 ='17' 
 AND i08.pe01 NOT IN (SELECT distinct i01_KIN.p01 AS fld81 FROM i01_KIN)
)
```

Comment: `&&` is legitimate in MySQL SQL. [Reference here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html). Share and enjoy.